# Reading value from nested NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nested, nsdictionary

Im having trouble accessing a value within an NSDictionary, I'd like to be reading the value for the "user5" key, I can't work out what is going on or how to access this value, Ive attached the screenshot produced by the debugger when i create a breakpoint:
[Here][1]

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: It's in the dictionary for key `users` in the dictionary for key `-LMN...` in `values`

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: so its reading from firebase and i currently have it implemented as so: 'code'

Comment: provide the print statement that shows that and the surrounding code

Comment: searchRef.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("found:")
            let values = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            
                print(values?.allValues as? NSDictionary)
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let c = child as! NSDictionary
                c.allValues
            }
            print(snapshot.value)

Comment: @Sh_Khan  sorry I can't format this properly :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let va = values["LMN9xAUOcgsw4c6GJb4"] as? [String:Any] {
   if let users = va["users"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let user = users["user5"] as? String {
           print(user)
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = NSDictionary()
print((datat.value(forKey: "Key1") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Key2") as! String)
```